# Why is the order of evaluation for function parameters unspecified in c++?

Tags: c++, order-of-execution, unspecified-behavior

The standard doesn't specify the order of evaluation of arguments with this line:

> The order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified.

What does

> Better code can be generated in the absence of restrictions on
>   expression evaluation order

imply?

What is the drawback in asking all the compilers to evaluate the function arguments Left to Right for example? What kinds of optimizations do compilers perform because of this unspecified spec?

Comment: Allowing the compiler to re-order the evaluation of the operands adds more room for optimization.

Comment: @Mysticial: Absurd as it might look, that should be an answer, and actually the *accepted* answer!

Comment: What kinds of optimizations do the compilers perform?

Comment: If I can think of an example I'll make that an answer.

Comment: Some calling conventions pass parameters right to left. Others pass left to right. It is sometimes more efficient to evaluate in the same order they are pushed.

Answer (score 29):

Allowing the compiler to re-order the evaluation of the operands adds more room for optimization.

Here's a completely made up example for illustration purposes.

Suppose the processor can:

- Issue 1 instruction each cycle.
- Execute an addition in 1 cycle.
- Execute a multiplication in 3 cycles.
- Can execute additions and multiplications at the same time.

Now suppose you have a function call as follows:

```
foo(a += 1, b += 2, c += 3, d *= 10);
```

If you were to execute this left-to-right on a processor without [OOE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution):

```
Cycle - Operation
0     -    a += 1
1     -    b += 2
2     -    c += 3
3     -    d *= 10
4     -    d *= 10
5     -    d *= 10
```

Now if you allow the compiler to re-order them: (and start the multiplication first)

```
Cycle - Operation
0     -    d *= 10
1     -    a += 1, d *= 10
2     -    b += 2, d *= 10
3     -    c += 3
```

So 6 cycles vs. 4 cycles.

Again this is completely contrived. Modern processors are much more complicated than that. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple example. Suppose you have a function call as follows:

```
// assume that p is a pointer to an integer
foo(*p * 3, bar(), *p * 3 + 1);
```

The compiler needs to dereference `p` twice (and do some computations based on the result) and call `bar` once. If the compiler is clever, it might reorder the evaluation to

```
int temp = *p * 3;
foo(temp, bar(), temp + 1);
```

That way it has to do the "dereference, multiply by 3" only once. This is known as common subexpression eliminiation.

Comment: To be fair, even languages that guarantee order of evaluation can do this, provided they can sort-of prove that the value of `p` cannot change in between. Of course, with the C memory model that's pretty much impossible to guarantee, which is probably why undefined order of evaluation is necessary to achieve this optimisation.

Comment: If it could be proven, the optimizer could reorder the evaluation by the as-if-rule, even if the order is prescribed by the standard.